# Synapse: Pass the output value (column name) from lookup TO a parameter of a pipeline

Tags: azure-synapse, lookup-tables

I am having below code,

I have a lookup, which gets ONLY valid filename from Meta.

I wanted to call a pipeline when the file count is greater than 0 ,when it is empty pipeline should do nothing but not fail.

```
The Look is having " Select file_count from table"
But here the count value is 0 , which is why I am getting below error. 


cannot be evaluated because property 'firstRow' doesn't exist, available properties are 'effectiveIntegrationRuntime, billingReference, durationInQueue'."
```

When the file_count > 0 Pipeline has no issues. But when file_count = 0 then it is failing with error above.

[image]

Comment: As you have nor checked the first roe only in lookup so in output there is not firstRow node or value in output thatts the reason you are getting an error

Comment: can you add sample lookup output and what you need in next activity form it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message indicates that the lookup activity is not returning any rows, and therefore, the 'firstRow' property is not available. Error is not because the value of file_count is 0. To check if the lookup file or table has value, you can give the condition as `@activity(' Get valid manifest files ').output,'firstRow'` to check if firstrow exists.

If you want to check if firstRow exists and then value of file_count is greater than 0 , you can combine both the expressions and give it like below expression.

```
@and(contains(activity('Get valid manifest files').output,'firstRow'),greater(activity('Get valid manifest files').output.firstRow.File_Count,0))
```

This expression will be true only if Firstrow exists and value of file_count is greater than 0